# Among those, which one is being sarcastic?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

You are very good at this for your age.

You are very good at this despite your age.

You are so old, and you are good at this.

You are so old, but you are good at this.

Comment: Is this a test question?  It is not possible to determine which of these is sarcastic without more information.  Are you talking to a six year old or a ninety year old?  Are they good at keeping mushy peas down, using the potty, or pole vaulting?

Comment: The first might be said to a child, the second to an older person. The other two might be said teasingly to an older person - cheeky, but not sarcastic.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without more context.  Depending on the facts and your tone.  All or none could be sarcastic; however, the first one is the most likely answer because of its vagueness.

Answer (score 2):

Without further information as to context, none of these is sarcastic.